# Проект по умолчанию в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Есть ли в шторме проект по умолчанию? Если есть, то как его отключить. Я запускаю шторм, а у меня всё время открывается старый проект. Я жду в меню close project и выбираю нужный. Как сделать чтобы сразу меню с проектами открывалось, а не грузился не понятно какой

Answer (score 4):

1. вариант: каждый раз после работы закрывать проект через `Close Project` (Закрыть проект)
2. вариант: идем в настройки `File` → `Settings` → `Appearance & Behavior` → `System Settings` и убираем галочку с пункта `Reopen last project on startup`

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я тоже не использую автозагрузку предыдущих проектов.